# How and What to write in Registry to Auto-Restart a Program on Windows Startup

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, registry

I want to design the program in such a way that whenever it is installed , it should be auto restart on Windows Startup on the All USERS of the Windows...

My foremost requirement is that I can not give my program Admin Rights as it has to run in Limited Account or sometimes on Admin accounts with UAC enabled to max level...

What and Where should I write in Registry to achieve this.. or If Registry can not be modified for all users without admin privileges then Is there any alternate way to restart the Program after Windows Bootup ?

As far as I know, one alternate way is to install our program in Start Up folder .. however Please let me know if it is feasible to install the program without admin privileges in startup folder for all users and can all write operations be performed in startup folder even for limited account user ?

Comment: If there easy/obvious/supported ways to get around the security system, what would be the point of having a security system?

Comment: Imagine if this were possible. A limited user could put anything they wanted into the global Startup group, and it would run the next time an Administrator logs on. Machine would be totally compromised.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: You can't. Vista and above (and XP if you're not running under a power user or administrator account) has no write-access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

You also need administrative privileges to install an application for all users; without that privilege, you can only install for the current logged in user. This means that installing a shortcut in the "all users" startup folder won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Barring an exploitable security vulnerability, only Admin accounts can do things that affect other users on the machine, such as setting keys in HEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, registering programs to run for other users via the Task Scheduler, or installing a service.  This is by design.